# iTunesConnect Screenshot order is confusing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

In the "new" **ItunesConnect** when I upload preview screenshots for a new app, the first picture I upload appears on the far right, and the next pictures I upload will all appear left to it. So the last picture will be on the far left.

Which is confusing because we in western countries are used to left-to-right. Now I don't know which picture will be shown first in iTunes for the user? Will it be the one on the **far right** or the one on the **far left**?

Comment: Instead of down voting at least explain why you did it.
This is a serious question - because once you submit an app, you'll have to wait weeks in the worst case for them to review it. Now imagine getting your app in store and the screenshots are in the wrong order. You'd have to upload again, and you'd have to wait weeks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you upload all your screenshots, you can just drag & drop them in the order you want.
I don't know what is iTunesConnect's order is using, but while you can change it after upload them, it's not really important, is it?

Finally, when your app will be release, the order used by itunes will be **left to right**. Exactly the same order as in itunes connect.

**Edit**

To be more clear, this is an example, supposing I have 4 pictures named 1, 2, 3, 4. If when I saved it in itunes connect I have the following order: 1, 2, 3, 4, I will have the same order in itunes, which is: 1, 2, 3, 4, even if I didn't have this order when I upload them.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The last paragraph was all I needed. Thank you for answering and being helpful instead of down voting like a child ;)

Comment: Wait no, no you edited again. The order in ITC is right to left. The last one you upload will be on the far left!

Comment: Well, don't think about the order when you upload it, but just the order you have when you saved it. So, the first one on the left in itunes connect will be the first one on the left on the apple store

Comment: Okay, that's all I needed to know. In the old ITC the screenshots got displayed in the order the were uploaded, that is why I got confused. Right-to-left display is illogical and user-unfriendly.